# VS 2015 Diagnostic Tools window is blank

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2015, profiling, debug-diagnostic-tool

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I'm trying to use Diagnostic Tools and somehow that window is always blank. There is nothing displayed in that window. There is no error too. I tried the same with empty IDE, loading a project, and debugging the project but in all scenarios it is completely blank, just the window heading and nothing else.

I've seen other issues with Diagnostic tools such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247517/vs-2015-diagnostic-tools-failed-unexpectedly), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247517/vs-2015-diagnostic-tools-failed-unexpectedly) but I can't find anybody facing issue like this.

I tried reinstalling VS and also checked by installing VS 2015 Update 2, nothing helped.

It would be great help for me if anybody got any idea why it is happening or what can I do to find the issue or fix it?

Product version: Visual Studio Enterprise Edition 2015 with Update2

OS: Windows 7 Enterprise Service pack 1

Comment: I have the same problem with windows 10 and an old pc. On another pc it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this same issue with VS 2017. For me, the problem is that my laptop has a 4K display, but I'm also connected to exernal monitors that are not 4K. VS seems to have trouble rendering the diagnostics tool panel when I move the VS window around or connect/disconnect the external displays. If I restart VS and open it on the desired monitor, it starts displaying again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to enable logs for the diagnostics tools based on instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35299055/5225869). Probably, log contents can provide some hint for the reason of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Starting VS2015 as Administrator worked for me as a workaround.

The only error that I found in logs (enabled as in Andrey's answer) was this one:

```
 Error --- datawarehouse.cpp --- Path should be secure at this point: 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CLIENTDIAGNOSTICS\APPRESPONSIVENESS\..\MemoryProfiler\DataModel'
```

Otherwise logs looked fine, with entries of `Debug` and `Info` importance only and nothing suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when I blocked with SRP executable file of Microsoft Edge WebView2:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\110.0.1587.50\msedgewebview2.exe"
So, I you wish Diagnostic Tools working, you need to have [Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section) installed, or allowed it for execution.

To install it, run the file with arguments:

```
MicrosoftEdgeWebView2RuntimeInstallerX64.exe /silent /install
```