# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Diagnostic Tools no longer shows events at all

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, diagnostic-tools

Okay so it appears in the last week or so my Enterprise Visual Studio 2017 can no longer get the 'Events' to populate at all for the Diagnostics tool.  The tool shows up and runs just fine, it however does not have any events even as I can see and when clicking the filter.  Except funny enough it can load symbols and still hit breakpoints and even tell me: "Yep I got your breakpoint event".  The problem being I used it a lot for ADO.NET and data tracking to double click an item and get the 'historical debugging'.  Basically the 'Filter' says I don't have events yet and even if it hits a breakpoint it only acknowledges the one event.

[image: Diagnostics Not Working Picture]

Things I have tried:

1. Deleting the SUO files for the solution I am on.
2. Checking the Debug General Options against another Dev whose is working.  And ensuring 'Enable Just My Code' is on.
3. Changed Configuration settings from Debug to Release and changing CPU configs to see on the off chance this could be it.
4. Shut down the PC and rebooted.

I tried suggestions on this thread:
[Visual Studio 2015 diagnostic tools no longer working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308334/visual-studio-2015-diagnostic-tools-no-longer-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screen shot, it just has the break events, no IntelliTrace Events.

(1) Please add a breakpoint in your app, and then debug it, after the breakpoint was hit, check the Event.

(2) I think you could enable the IntelliTrace under TOOLS->Options->IntelliTrace, please enable IntelliTrace. Debug it again.

(3) Of course, not very sure that whether it is related to the project type, for example, just create a simple Winform app, test it again.

Comment: It cannot get other events that's the problem.  1. Already did that, what am I looking for? 2. Does nothing, Intellitrace was already enabled.  3. Interesting it does work now for a NEW project.  It has to do with the solution or something similar.  This was a multi project solution mostly with Winforms and data access libraries in .NET.

Comment: Interesting it is now working on the project it would not work on.  Almost like doing the new project and then going back to the existing one gave it a reboot.  Changing settings did nothing, merely opening a new project and trying it again fixed it.  I don't know if this is a cached setting somewhere or a registry that got updated, but it is working again.

Comment: @djangojazz, Glad to know that it works well now, as you said that you reboot, maybe it meets VS loaded issue or the project itself, anyway, glad to know that it works well. If my reply provide a correct path, you could mark it as the answer, so we could close this case. Have a nice day:)